# Event conversion from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, event-handling

Any guidance will be appreciated:
I am converting I vb.net project I have finished to C#. I don't know how to approach the event handling in C#. I have a security alert event set up in my UserAccount class:

```
Public Class UserAccount

Private m_UserAccountID As Guid
Private m_Username As String
Private m_Password As String
Private m_Email As String

Public Event SecurityAlert(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
```

which then I raise in an Authentication method:

```
Public Function Authenticate(ByVal U As String, ByVal P As String) As Boolean

    RaiseEvent SecurityAlert(U, P)

    If m_Username = U And m_Password = P Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False

End Function
```

which then I handle in my Login Form:

```
Private Sub objUserAccount_SecurityAlert(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)     Handles objUserAccount.SecurityAlert
    If username = "sam" And password = "333" Then
        MessageBox.Show("This is a security breach! This employee has been fired!")
        End
    End If

End Sub
```

I have the same Class and form in my C# project but I'm confused as to where and how to set up my delagate and dealing with these parameters and not the object and EventArgs. Like I said, any guidance will be appreciated. This was a class project from the summer that I'm converting on my own because I want to advance my knowledge.

Ok so like I said have done this so far:

```
namespace BusinessObjects
{
public delegate void SecurityAlert(string username, string password);

public class UserAccount
{
    private Guid m_UserAccountID;
    private String m_Username; 
    private String m_Password;
    private String m_Email;

    public event SecurityAlert Alert;
```

then in my class Authentication method I tried to raise it:

```
Alert += new SecurityAlert(U,P);
```

I seen from Jeffery's post that that was incorrect and changed it to:

```
Alert += new SecurityAlert(Alert);
```

which makes sense because it looks like that I am now referencing the Alert method that handles the event which I have set up in my Log In form:

```
private void Alert(String username, String password){
        if(username == "sam" && password == "333"){
            MessageBox.Show("This is a security breach! This employee has been fired!");
        }
    }
```

But my UserAccount and Login Form are two differnt classes so how can they reference eachother? I get an error:

```
Alert += new SecurityAlert(Alert); Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of creating, firing, and handling an event in C#?  What problems are you having with those attempts?  What resources have you looked into on how to perform those actions in C#?

Comment: If you don't know how to define an event with another signature then *say that*.  If you have a program that is currently not working *show us what you have* and explain what, *specifically*, isn't working about it.

Comment: As resources started with msdn but I didn't find any documentation specific to parameters other than object and Eventargs. I checked this site but I found nothing relative to my project. I looked at some youtube also. So far I put the delegate outside of my class but within my namespace: public delegate void SecurityAlert(string username, string password). Then created a field in my UserAccount class: public event SecurityAlert Alert; Then in my Authentication method did: Alert += new SecurityAlert(U,P); Got some errors and really didn't know to go about creating the Handler in my Login Form.

Comment: So it looks like you're basically there, or at least close.  As I've told you, several times now, just include the actual code in your question, and describe the exact errors that you are getting.  It's wasteful of everyone's time when you're 90% there to ask someone to explain it to you from the beginning.

Comment: I updated my question with code and error. I understand showing everyone where exactly I am having problems from the work I have done.

Comment: Can you assist me @Servy I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some very useful information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)

You delegate would look like this:

```
public delegate void SecurityAlert(string username, string password);
```

This is how you would include it in your class for use:

```
public class UserAccount
{
    public event SecurityAlert OnSecurityAlert;
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx) is information on raising your custom event.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) is some additional information on events in c#

Register the event:

```
UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount();
userAccount.OnSecurityAlert += new SecurityAlert(OnSecurityAlert);
```

Event handler Method:

```
private void OnSecurityAlert(string username, string password)
{

}
```

Comment: if you can, can you please read my edited code up top. I'm stuck as to what the compiler is asking. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You have to register the event on the property of the instance of UserAccount you created. See my register line. It is userAccountInstance.Alert += new SecurityAlert(Alert); The way you have it, you are registering a new SecuityAlert on the Event hander method, not the event property.

Comment: I did exactly as you described. I am registering inside my Authentication method: UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount();
userAccount.OnSecurityAlert += new SecurityAlert(OnSecurityAlert); and the error highlights this and says "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'. I'm stumped.

Comment: Unless you changed the name of your event handler method it should be userAccount.OnSecurityAlert += new SecurityAlert(Alert);

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of differences in the way Visual Basic and C# deal with events.  First, Visual Basic allows you to specify the event handler's signature on the same line as where you declare the event; C# makes you split it into two lines (define a delegate type, then declare the event).  Second, C# doesn't have an equivalent to Visual Basic's `Handles` clause.  Instead, you have to register and de-register events manually, a lot like you would do with Visual Basic's `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`.

Here's an example of a class that defines an event, and raises it inside a method:

```
class UserAccount
{
    public delegate void SecurityAlertHandler(String username, String password);
    public event SecurityAlertHandler SecurityAlert;

    public void RaiseSecurityAlert(String u, String p)
    {
        SecurityAlert(u, p);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a class that registers an event handler and handles the event:

```
class AlertHandler
{
    public void RegisterHandler(UserAccount toMonitor)
    {
        toMonitor.SecurityAlert += HandleSecurityAlert;
    }

    private void HandleSecurityAlert(String username, String password)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got event: " + username + " => " + password);
    }
}
```

And here's some code that you can step through in a debugger to watch it do its thing:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserAccount ua = new UserAccount();
        AlertHandler ah = new AlertHandler();
        ah.RegisterHandler(ua);
        ua.RaiseSecurityAlert("User", "pwd");
    }
```

Since Visual Basic's `Handles` clause registers the event handlers automatically, you might be wondering where to put the event registration (`toMonitor.SecurityAlert += HandleSecurityAlert` in our example).  In your case, that would probably be in your login form's OnLoad method.  You'll also want to de-register the event using `-=`.  You'd put that in the same place you set `objUserAccount` to Nothing in your Visual Basic code.